# Self hosting SignalR in console app, throws Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.... when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, visual-studio-2017

I'm self hosting SignalR in a console app. The code works fine if visual studio is installed on the machine. However, when I build and send to a machine without visual studio, the code fails when it tries to start signalR, giving the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core,
>   Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Using Visual Studio 2017 to compile the code.

### Package config

```
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="105.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.3.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.linux" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.osx" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.v110_xp" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.net45" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

### App config

```
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I just need to add a line in the config file and all works fine. To solve add the entry "loadFromRemoteSources" as below.

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/loadfromremotesources-element

Answer (score 1):

In my case of a selfhost application with the signalr hub I found out another issue with such exception - Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core. I have console app too, but my signalr hub is placed in the separate assembly, that are referenced by head(startup) console assembly. Because of that, I was forced to install and then update versions of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core on startup console assembly as well.